# Ansible Molecule SSL Errors

Tags: python, ansible, molecule

I am running Ansible molecule test cases. However, I am seeing SSL validation errors!
Does someone aware of this error? Any alternatives to fix this problem?

More details below:

```
[root@ansible automation]# /root/.local/bin/molecule converge
INFO     default scenario test matrix: dependency, create, prepare, converge
INFO     Performing prerun...
INFO     Set ANSIBLE_LIBRARY=/root/.cache/ansible-compat/a11664/modules:/root/.ansible/plugins/modules:/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules
INFO     Set ANSIBLE_COLLECTIONS_PATHS=/root/.cache/ansible-compat/a11664/collections:/root/.ansible/collections:/usr/share/ansible/collections
INFO     Set ANSIBLE_ROLES_PATH=/root/.cache/ansible-compat/a11664/roles:/root/.ansible/roles:/usr/share/ansible/roles:/etc/ansible/roles
INFO     Using /root/.ansible/roles/dellemc.powerflex_storage symlink to current repository in order to enable Ansible to find the role using its expected full name.
INFO     Running default > dependency
INFO     Running ansible-galaxy collection install -v --force community.docker:>=1.9.1
WARNING  Retrying execution failure 1 of: ansible-galaxy collection install -v --force community.docker:>=1.9.1
ERROR    Command returned 1 code:
Using /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg as config file
Process install dependency map
|
ERROR! Unknown error when attempting to call Galaxy at 'https://galaxy.ansible.com/api/': <urlopen error [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:618)>
```

Ansible Details:

```
ansible 2.9.27
  config file = /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = [u'/root/.ansible/plugins/modules', u'/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
  ansible python module location = /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible
  executable location = /usr/bin/ansible
  python version = 2.7.5 (default, Nov 16 2020, 22:23:17) [GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-44)]
```

Python & Molecule Details:

```
Python 3.6.8
molecule 3.6.1 using python 3.6
    ansible:2.9.27
    delegated:3.6.1 from molecule
    docker:1.1.0 from molecule_docker requiring collections: community.docker>=1.9.1
```

Curious question, Ansible cfg is pointing to old Python version. But, molecule is using the latest one. Does someone aware of updating this part as well?

Comment: `Curious question, Ansible cfg is pointing to old Python version. But, molecule is using the latest one. Does someone aware of updating this part as well?` <= hard to tell without knowing exactly how you installed ansible but chances are => `pip2 uninstall ansible && pip3 install ansible`. Regarding your ssl problem: are you behind a proxy ? What happens when you manually `curl https://galaxy.ansible.com` ?